# .NET invisible items in combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm loading Strings to a Combobox -

```
cboIndexLanguage.Items.Add("ThisLanguage")
```

i would like to make several of these items invisible.

Comment: Just don't add them or if they are already added You may remove them...

Comment: why do you want to do this?  Do you want an entry (ie empty line), or no entry at all?

Comment: i want the text value to exist but i don't want to show it.
the indexs that they have are important and i want to keep them thats why i do it.

Comment: If the index is important store it in the Tag property for a ComboBoxItem.

Comment: imho a ComboBox with "invisible" lines is visually confusing. As Masood suggested (if I understand his comment correctly) one strategy is to maintain a "master list" of valid combobox entries and re-populate the ComboBox as needed. What you wish to achieve can much more easily be done with a ListView with CheckBoxes, with a little bit of advanced programming : i.e., you can show ALL the items, but prohibit checking those items which are not available, and you can also set their background color to indicate they're not available. If you want to see this code, ask, and I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. It can be done by binding DataTable object:

```
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "VALUE";
            comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("VALUE");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row[0] = i;
                row[1] = "val"+i;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            comboBox.DataSource = dt;
```

Then simply found an item you want to hide and hide it (by setting as deleted):

```
dt.Select("ID = 2").First().Delete();
```

Or unhide all:

```
dt.RejectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a `CB_SETMINVISIBLE` message for each item.

OR

simply don't set the Text value!

Later edit:

```
int invItems = 5;
Message msg = new Message();
msg.Msg = CB_SETMINVISIBLE;
msg.LParam = 0;
msg.WParam = invItems;
msg.HWnd = combo.Handle;
MessageWindow.SendMessage(ref msg);
```

OR invoke this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, long wParam, long lParam);
```

Comment: how do i set the CB_SETMINVISIBLE in C#?

Comment: Please see my edit. I would go with the second approach, though (i.e. set empty string for the Text property)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
it looks to me that MessageWindow.SendMessage only available in windows CE...

is there any other simplier solution to it?

Comment: While CB_SETMINVISIBLE contains "invisible", it doesn't make anything invisible.  It sets the minimum number of items visible in the dropdown.  ComboBox doesn't have a way to hide items, just don't add them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an other list to keep strings and show wanted items to user by combo box.To do that you can define a Refresh_Combo_Method that clears combo box items and copies item from list of string to combo , then indexes was in main list.

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string>();
colorList.Add ("Red");
colorList.Add ("Green");
colorList.Add ("Yellow");
colorList.Add ("Purple");
colorList.Add ("Orange");
...
colorList.Remove("Red");
colorList.Insert(2, "White");
colorList[colorList.IndexOf("Yellow")] = "Black";
colorList.Clear();


...

combobox.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In thread-safe way you can do it pretty simple (if you only want to play with colors):

```
private delegate void SetBackColorDelegate(int index, Color color);
private void SetBackColor(int index, Color color)
    {
        if (cboIndexLanguage.InvokeRequired)
        {
            cboIndexLanguage.Invoke(new SetBackColorDelegate(SetBackColor), new object[] { index, color });
        }
        else
        {
            cboIndexLanguage.Items[index].BackColor = color;
        }
    }
```

In other way, you can just remove items from combo box but save them in some data structure f.ex:

```
class ComboElement
{
     public String ComboElementText { get; set; }
     public int Index { get; set; }

    public ComboElement(String elementText, int index)
    {
       ComboElementText = elementText;
       Index = index;
    }
}

//* List of hidden elements.
List<ComboElement> hiddenElements = new List<ComboElement>();
```

then you want to show it again, you can take it from here, and insert into the right place (you know index).

Answer (score 0):

add these to your combobox

```
class MyCboItem
{
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Visible) return Value;
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```